# 1950s Short Story - Naive Aliens

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens, first-contact

Short-short story, American author, read in the `1960s, probably in an anthology but might have been a magazine. A pair of gullible aliens are on their first trip to Earth. A (seemingly) friendly human takes them under his wing and shows them the sights. They are very happy, unaware, at the end, that the Earthman is leading them toward a cage.

Comment: Possibly this one? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Youth_(Asimov_short_story)

Comment: No, that isn't it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This story is [*The Underprivileged*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56901) (1963) by Brian Aldiss. Three alien refugees from a war-torn planet land on a human-colonized world, are given the grand tour & see how wonderful things are. Congratulating themselves on being given permission to settle there, they " - turned and hurried into the big scarlet-painted cage."